# SOLR query, value of field 1 is same as field 2, OR field 1 is empty

Tags: solr, field

Got a SOLR query question here, how do I construct my query to suit the following condition:

(value of field 1 is same as field 2) OR (field 1 is empty)

Cheers

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- value of field 1 is same as field 2

  As far as I know there is no good way to do this at query-time. So do it at index-time, i.e. when indexing, run the comparison and put the result in a field, then query that field.
- field 1 is empty

  ```
    -field1:[* TO *]
  ```